# Grails: Domain model relationships based on legacy database

Tags: grails, relationship, domain-model, table-relationships

I'm creating a Grails application that takes data from an existing legacy database (that's can't be modified) and I'm trying to wrap my head around how to represent table relationships in the domain model classes.

Here's some sample data:

```
Table 1 Columns: pID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
Table 1 ID is composite made up of pID and LastName

Table 2 Columns: pID, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber, FaxNumber
Table 1 ID is composite made up of pID, EmailAddress, PhoneNumber

Table 3 Columns: pID, Occupation
Table 3 ID is just pID
```

How could I represent these three tables and their relationships (via the pID column) with domain model classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395553/grails-best-approach-to-dealing-with-an-existing-database/21395598#21395598). Try to use the plugin.

Comment: I actually used that plugin, but it does not create relationships between the classes.  It simply creates one class per table (with no regard to how it connects to other tables)

Comment: What have you got yet using the database reverse engineer plugin? Add those domain classes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Table3{
  String id, occupation
}

class User implements Serializable{
  Table3 pID
  String firstName, lastName, middleName
  static mapping = {
        // need name maping: 
        id composite: ['pID', 'lastName']
    }
  //!!!Add equals and hashCode
}
class Profile implements Serializable{
  Table3 pID  
  String emailAddress, phoneNumber, faxNumber
  static mapping = {
        // need name maping: 
        id composite: ['pID', 'emailAddress', 'phoneNumber']
    }
  //!!!Add equals and hashCode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the tutorial gives guidance on relationships:
http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-db-reverse-engineer/docs/manual/guide/4%20Tutorial.html

```
6. Configure the reverse engineering process.

Add these configuration options to grails-app/conf/Config.groovy:

grails.plugin.reveng.packageName = 'com.revengtest'
grails.plugin.reveng.versionColumns = [other: 'nonstandard_version_name']
grails.plugin.reveng.manyToManyTables = ['user_role']
grails.plugin.reveng.manyToManyBelongsTos = ['user_role': 'role', 'author_books': 'book']
```